# Kmeans inter and intra cluster ordering

Tags: r

I am wondering what other people are doing with K-means cluster ordering. I am making heatmaps (mainly of [ChIP-Seq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip-Sequencing) data) and getting nice looking figures with a custom heatmap function (based off of R's built in heatmap function). However, I'd like two improvements. The first is to order my clusters based on decreasing average value. For instance, the following code:

```
fit = kmeans(data, 8, iter.max=50, nstart=10)
d = data.frame(data, symbol)
d = data.frame(d, fit$cluster)
d = d[order(d$fit.cluster),]
```

gives me a data.frame ordered on a clusters column. What is the best way to order the rows such that the 8 clusters are in order of their respective means?

Second, do you recommend sorting the rows WITHIN each cluster from highest mean value to lowest? This will impose a more organized look onto the data, but may fool a non-cautious observer into inferring something that he perhaps should not. If you do recommend this, how would you do it most efficiently?

Comment: means of what? One of the variables used for clustering or something else?

Comment: Means of the values in each cluster. For instance, if each cluster is 30 rows in a data.frame and the data.frame has 10 columns upon which k-means clustering is performed, I'd want the mean of the 300 values in each cluster. Could also use the centroid.

Comment: The centroid is isn't a number for each cluster, it is a point in 10-d space and hence each cluster centroid has 10 coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an exact answer to what you ask, but perhaps you might consider seriation instead of k-means clustering. It is a bit like ordination rather than clustering, but one end result is a heatmap of the seriated data which sounds similar to what you seem to be doing with k-means followed by a specifically ordered heatmap.

There is an R package for seriation, called `seriation` and it has a vignette, which you can get [directly from CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seriation/index.html)

I'll answer the specifics of the Q once I've cooked up an example to try.

Ok - proper answer following on from your comment above. First some dummy data - 3 clusters of 10 samples each, on each of 3 variables.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(A = c(rnorm(10, 2), rnorm(10, -2), rnorm(10, -2)),
                  B = c(rnorm(10, 0), rnorm(10, 5), rnorm(10, -2)),
                  C = c(rnorm(10, 0), rnorm(10, 0), rnorm(10, -10)))

## randomise the rows
dat <- dat[sample(nrow(dat)),]
clus <- kmeans(scale(dat, scale = FALSE), centers = 3, iter.max = 50,
               nstart = 10)

## means of n points in each cluster
mns <- sapply(split(dat, clus$cluster), function(x) mean(unlist(x)))

## order the data by cluster with clusters ordered by `mns`, low to high
dat2 <- do.call("rbind", split(dat, clus$cluster)[order(mns)])

## heatmaps
## original first, then reordered:
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
image(1:3, 1:30, t(data.matrix(dat)), ylab = "Observations", 
      xlab = "Variables", xaxt = "n", main = "Original")
axis(1, at = 1:3)
image(1:3, 1:30, t(data.matrix(dat2)), ylab = "Observations", 
      xlab = "Variables", xaxt = "n", main = "Reordered")
axis(1, at = 1:3)
layout(1)
```

Yielding:

[image: Original and reordered heatmaps]

Comment: Excellent! I want to give it a try and make sure I don't run into any issues before I accept. Thanks so much for coming back!

Comment: No probs @Ron post a comment or edit your Question and I'll see it as I've favourite-d the Q

Comment: I've just had someone come to me trying to do this, but weren't getting the results out they expected.  I think we may need an `order(rank(` rather than `order(order`.  

For instance if we have `mns  <- c(0.18, 0.19, -0.27, 0.24, 0.32, -0.05)` we'd want the third group to be listed first, and the 5th group listed last.  If we have `clus <- 1:6` then `clus[order(order(mns)[clus])]` gives the 2nd element last, but `clus[order(rank(mns)[clus])]` correctly gives the 5th element.

We want to sort the data by the rank of the cluster-mean.  I know it's an old answer, but people still look here.

Comment: @GavinKelly Thanks for following-up; doesn't matter if this is old or not if there is an issue. The sorting does seems to work *for this dataset*. I have however modified the code block to do the ordering of the data a little differently, which should be more general. It gives the same results for this data set. Basically I'm now splitting the data up by cluster into a list, one component per cluster. Then I reorder the components from low to high using `order(mns)`, before `rbind()`ing the now sorted list components back into a data frame.