# Ordering clustered points using Kmeans and R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have set of data (of 5000 points with 4 dimensions) that I have clustered using kmeans in R.

**I want to order the points in each cluster by their distance to the center of that cluster.**

Very simply, the data looks like this (I am using a subset to test out various approaches):

```
id  Ans Acc Que Kudos
1   100 100 100 100
2   85  83  80  75
3   69  65  30  29
4   41  45  30  22 
5   10  12  18  16
6   10  13  10  9
7   10  16  16  19
8   65  68  100 100
9   36  30  35  29
10  36  30  26  22
```

Firstly, I used the following method to cluster the dataset into 2 clusters:

```
(result <- kmeans(data, 2))
```

This returns a kmeans object that has the following [methods: 
cluster, centers etc.](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html)

**But I cannot figure out how to compare each point and produce an ordered list.**

Secondly, I tried the seriation approach as suggested by another SO user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786665/kmeans-inter-and-intra-cluster-ordering)

I use these commands:

```
clus <- kmeans(scale(x, scale = FALSE), centers = 3, iter.max = 50, nstart = 10)
mns <- sapply(split(x, clus$cluster), function(x) mean(unlist(x)))
result <- dat[order(order(mns)[clus$cluster]), ]
```

Which seems to produce an ordered list but if I bind it to the labeled clusters (using the following cbind command):

```
result <- cbind(x[order(order(mns)[clus$cluster]), ],clus$cluster)
```

I get the following result, which does not appear to be ordered correctly:

```
id  Ans Acc Que Kudos   clus
1   3   69  65  30  29  1
2   4   41  45  30  22  1
3   5   10  12  18  16  2
4   6   10  13  10  9   2
5   7   10  16  16  19  2
6   9   36  30  35  29  2
7   10  36  30  26  22  2
8   1   100 100 100 100 1
9   2   85  83  80  75  2
10  8   65  68  100 100 2
```

I don't want to be writing commands willy-nilly but understand how the approach works.  If anyone could help out or spread some light on this, it would be really great.

EDIT:::::::::::

As the clusters can be easily plotted, I'd imagine there is a more straightforward way to get and rank the distances between points and the center.

The centers for the above clusters (when using k = 2) are as follows.  But I do not know how to get and compare this with each individual point.

```
     Ans    Accep     Que      Kudos
1 83.33333 83.66667 93.33333 91.66667
2 30.28571 30.14286 23.57143 20.85714
```

NB::::::::

I don't need top use kmeans but I want to specify the number of clusters and retrieve an ordered list of points from those clusters.

Comment: This is a good question...check that you are not using the ID to cluster(I guess there are cases where you may want to, but it is unlikely)

Comment: Cool, I don't want to cluster the ids, oversight on my behalf. I will amend the question.  thanks..j

Comment: I believe that `kmeans()` also returns the final cluster centers.  From there, it shouldn't be too hard to compute the distance from each point to the center of its cluster.

Comment: Hi @Jack Maney,, you are right, it replies with the cluster means for example: Cluster means:
     X.Ans  X.Accep   X.Ques  X.Kudos
1 83.33333 83.66667 93.33333 91.66667
2 30.28571 30.14286 23.57143 20.85714 but I don't know how to access the clustered data points to compare distances.  I have a feeling that this is quite straightforward but I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: You have the data points (ie the same data that you fed into `kmeans()`).  You have the cluster assignments and centers of each cluster.  What, exactly, is confusing you about computing distances between each point and the center of that point's cluster?

Comment: But the centres have four dimensions and I have the original data not the computed data points ..... sorry, I hope this makes sense as I am trying to grasp this better.

Comment: So what?  Compute the distances.  What's holding you back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example that does what you ask, using the first example from `?kmeans`. It is probably not terribly efficient, but is something to build upon.

```
#Taken straight from ?kmeans
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
cl <- kmeans(x, 2)

x <- cbind(x,cl = cl$cluster)

#Function to apply to each cluster to 
# do the ordering
orderCluster <- function(i,data,centers){
    #Extract cluster and center
dt <- data[data[,3] == i,]
ct <- centers[i,]

    #Calculate distances
dt <- cbind(dt,dist = apply((dt[,1:2] - ct)^2,1,sum))
    #Sort
dt[order(dt[,4]),]
}

do.call(rbind,lapply(sort(unique(cl$cluster)),orderCluster,data = x,centers = cl$centers))
```

Comment: Thanks @joran, I upvoted you and will accept tomorrow once I have a better understanding of it.  I do want fully understand the approach.  Can I ask you a quick question? Does this approach work with multi-dimensional datasets? I just want to make sure that my approach is correct and that I do not have to use some form of MDS etc.  Thanks again.

Comment: @slotishtype Yes, the main things you'll want to adjust are the specific number of dimensions (I've hard coded this in several places for data with only 2 columns) and the choice of distance metric; I've used Euclidean distance here, which should be appropriate for kmeans.

Comment: Brill.  Thanks for your help, will accept tomorrow once I play around with it

Comment: Hey @joran, just wondering could you (briefly) explain the following lines:  dt <- data[data[,3] == i,] ct <- centers[i,] dt <- cbind(dt,dist = apply((dt[,1:2] - ct)^2,1,sum)) (especially the last line as I think that is hard-coded for your specific example but am unsure of the how vector access is organised).

Comment: `dt` is data from cluster `i`; `ct` is the center of cluster `i`. Add `browser()` just before the `cbind` line and run the code. Then play around with running pieces of the line you don't understand so you can see what each component is doing, and what the objects are.